# C++ equivalent of Python's __getattrr__(self, name)

Tags: c++

One of the things I like about Python is the way you [customize attribute access](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access):

```python
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if some_predicate(name):
            # ...
        else:
            # Default behaviour
            raise AttributeError
```

My question is: how could you achieve something similar in C++? Overloading the '.' operator would be one way to do it, but it's not allowed in C++.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) or [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), so in pure C++ it's impossible. There are hacks around it, but it's a lot or work and very complicated and usually involves special pre-compilers (like the Qt moc compiler).

Comment: C# has vast reflection capability; however your question above does not lend to the context too well for us C# folks to help you.  Is the content in a webbrowser already? Or is the content coming from a  webrequest?  However, we also know that Javascript is both a client and server side language as well as JQuery which has perhaps some of the finest attribute based abilities around.

Answer (score 3):

The main idea (i.e. providing attributes/functions dynamically) seems to be impossible without some template/macro magic - and that still wouldn't be run-time.

The closest thing I can imagine would be [overloading the -> operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). For example [`std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does that. Another way is to overload [the [] operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) - [`std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) being the most notable example.

Answer (score 2):

Real answer: Python is not C++. That kind of thing is Pythonic, but even if you could do it in C++, that would be terrible C++ code.

But if you really want to... everything in Python is just a dictionary. You can always just... re-write python in C++... (technically this is `__getitem__` but there's no way to do `__getattr__`).

```
class Foo {
public:
    Object* operator[](const std::string& name) 
    {
        if (some_predicate(name)) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error(); // or something
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, Object*> dict_; 
};
```