# C# equivalent of Python attribute customization / Javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, c#, python

One of the things I like about Python is the way you can [customize attribute access](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if some_predicate(name):
            # ...
        else:
            # Default behaviour
            raise AttributeError
```

You can do something similar more directly with Javascript's object literal notation.

My question is: how could you achieve something similar in C#? Overloading the '.' operator would be one way to do it, but it's not allowed in.

An example of the kind of thing I have in mind would be to define a class as such:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IDictionary Properties {get; private set;}
    public MyClass(IDictionary properties)
    {
        this.Properties = properties;
    }

    // Overload the '.' operator - not allowed!
    public static object operator .(MyClass inst, string name)
    {
        return inst.Properties[name];
    }
}
```

Use the class like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary properties = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "prop1", "value1"}, { "prop2", "value2"} };
        var my = new MyClass(properties);
        System.Console.WriteLine(my.prop1); // Doesn't work!
    }
}
```

(Note: I asked a similar question about C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690812/c-equivalent-of-pythons-getattrr-self-name); originally the same question, but split to make more specific for each language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a built-in support for this. You should derive your class from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override it's *TryGetMember/TrySetMember* by checking whether the property is valid using the dictionary passed to constructor.

Another option is to just use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a bag of properties.

However, while you do get some degree of functionality as dynamic languages have, you loose the C# native traits such as type safety, compile-time checking and IDE code completion support.

Comment: Added an answer with my example using DynamicObject for the record.

Answer (score 1):

@galenus gave me the accepted answer, but just for the record, I thought I'd add the code for my example updated to use [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class MyClass : DynamicObject
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; private set; }
    public MyClass(IDictionary<string, object> properties)
    {
        this.Properties = properties;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return Properties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "prop1", "value1"}, { "prop2", "value2"} };
        dynamic my = new MyClass(properties);
        System.Console.WriteLine(my.prop1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Properties.TryGetValue instead of checking the Properties.Keys.Contains in your code and then extracting the value. It's more succinct.

Comment: Of course, @galenus; I should have spotted that. I've updated the code to incorporate your suggestion.